# Ne ... quidem with preposition

Tags: grammar-choice, syntax, preposition, particle

What would be the translation of: *He does not play even with his brother*?

Could it be: *Ne cum fratre suo quidem ludit*?

Normally I have seen the structure *ne ... quidem* with a noun in the nominative case, but how is it when there is a preposition, or when the noun is in another case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Ne...quidem* can most definitely surround nouns in cases other than nominative:

- Apuleius, *Metamorphoses* 9.27 (genitive):

  > non sum barbarus nec agresti morum squalore praeditus nec ad exemplum naccinae truculentiae sulpuris te letali fumo necabo ac **ne iuris quidem** seueritate lege de adulteriis ad discrimen uocabo capitis tam uenustum tamque pulchellum puellum, sed plane cum uxore mea partiario tractabo.
- Caesar, *De bello gallico* 1.39.1 (accusative):

  > dum paucos dies ad Vesontionem rei frumentariae commeatusque causa moratur, ex percontatione nostrorum vocibusque Gallorum ac mercatorum, qui ingenti magnitudine corporum Germanos, incredibili virtute atque exercitatione in armis esse praedicabant – saepe numero sese cum his congressos **ne vultum quidem** atque aciem oculorum dicebant ferre potuisse – , tantus subito timor omnem exercitum occupavit, ut non mediocriter omnium mentes animosque perturbaret.
- Livy, *Ab urbe condita* 4.44.4 (accusative):

  > non suis beneficiis, non patrum iniuriis, non denique usurpandi libidine, cum liceat quod ante non licuerit, si non tribunum militarem, **ne quaestorem quidem** quemquam ex plebe factum.
- Cicero, *Pro Caelio* 24 (ablative):

  > et, si Asicio causa plus profuit quam nocuit invidia, huic oberit maledictum tuum qui istius facti non modo suspicione sed **ne infamia quidem** est aspersus?

It doesn't even have to surround nouns. It can even surround verbs and entire clauses:

- Cicero, *Lucullus* 49:

  > sic enim ascenditis: 'si tale visum obiectum est a deo dormienti ut probabile sit, cur non etiam ut valde veri simile; cur deinde non ut difficiliter a vero internoscatur, deinde ut **ne internoscatur quidem**, postremo ut nihil inter hoc et illud intersit.
- Cicero, *Pro Murena* 36:

  > non modo horum nihil ita fore putatum est sed, **ne cum esset factum quidem**, qua re ita factum esset intellegi potuit.
- Seneca the Younger, *Dialogi* 3.21.1:

  > nihil ergo in ira, **ne cum uidetur quidem** uehemens et deos hominesque despiciens, magnum, nihil nobile est.

If the noun is modified by an adjective or other modifier (e.g., dependent genitive), it appears that the *ne...quidem* mostly surrounds either the noun or the modifier. I didn't find any examples where it surrounds both, but such examples may exist.

- Cicero, *Pro Plancio* 12 (around adjective):

  > semper se dicet rogari voluisse, semper sibi supplicari; se M. Seium, qui **ne equestrem quidem** splendorem incolumem a calamitate iudici retinere potuisset, homini nobilissimo, innocentissimo, eloquentissimo, M. Pisoni, praetulisse; praeposuisse se Q. Catulo, summa in familia nato, sapientissimo et sanctissimo viro, non dico C. Serranum, stultissimum hominem – fuit enim tamen nobilis – non C. Fimbriam, novum hominem – fuit enim et animi satis magni et consili – sed Cn. Mallium, non solum ignobilem verum sine virtute, sine ingenio, vita etiam contempta ac sordida.

For simple prepositional phrases, the *ne...quidem* surrounds the preposition and noun/substantive.

- Cicero, *Pro S. Roscio Amerino* 52:

  > quippe, qui **ne in oppidum quidem** nisi perraro veniret.
- Cicero, *Pro Flacco* 8:

  > Tmolites ille vicanus, homo non modo nobis sed **ne inter suos quidem** notus, vos docebit qualis sit L. Flaccus?
- Pliny the Elder, *Naturalis historia* 16.3:

  > non pecudem his habere, non lacte ali, ut finitimis, **ne cum feris quidem** dimicare contingit omni procul abacto frutice.
- Apuleius, *De mundo* 25:

  > talis quippe humilitas deiecti et minus sublimis officii, **ne cum homine quidem** conuenit, qui sit uel paululum conscientiae celsioris.

If the noun that is the object of the preposition is modified by an adjective or other modifier, it appears once again that the *ne...quidem* surrounds either the preposition + noun or the preposition + modifier. As before, I didn't find any examples where it surrounds the entire prepositional phrase, but I didn't check every preposition; so such examples may exist.

- Livy, *Ab urbe condita* 9.19.15 (around preposition + noun):

  > non quidem Alexandro duce nec integris Macedonum rebus sed experti tamen sunt Romani Macedonem hostem aduersus Antiochum Philippum Persen non modo cum clade ulla sed **ne
  >   cum periculo quidem** suo.
- Cicero, *Pro S. Roscio Amerino* 39 (around preposition + noun):

  > de luxuria purgavit Erucius, cum dixit hunc **ne in convivio quidem** ullo fere interfuisse.
- P. Rutilius Lupus, *Schemata lexeos* 1.7 (around preposition + adjective):

  > item Hegesiae: 'Miseremini mei, iudices, quem coniurata tanta vis inimicorum oppugnat: miseremini   solitudinis, cui **ne in summo quidem** tempore [periculi] liberos adhibere ad communem calamitatem deprecandam licitum est: miseremini senectutis, quae me etiam sine ceteris malis graviter defatigat.
- Cicero, *In Verrem* 2.1.72 (around preposition + adjective [gerundive]):

  > de quo ne multa disseram tantum dico, secutum id esse Neronem et eius consilium: quod Cornelium lictorem occisum esse constaret, putasse non oportere esse cuiquam **ne in ulciscenda quidem** iniuria hominis occidendi potestatem.
- Cicero, *De oratore* 1.235 (around preposition + adjective [demonstrative]):

  > sed ego **ne cum ista quidem** arte pugno.
- Cicero, *Pro Quinctio* 88 (around preposition + dependent genitive):

  > postea sum usus adversarii testimonio, qui sibi eum nuper edidit socium quem, quo modo nunc intendit, **ne in vivorum quidem** numero tum demonstrat fuisse.

**Therefore**

To answer your first question, 'He does not play even with his brother' could be *ne cum fratre quidem suo ludit* or *ne cum suo quidem fratre ludit* (or possibly even *ne ludit quidem cum fratre suo*). As is typical, the various arrangements can affect the emphasis of the sentence – for example:

- *ne cum fratre quidem suo ludit*, 'He doesn't play even with his own *brother* [much less his own sister].'
- *ne cum suo quidem fratre ludit*, 'He doesn't play even with *his own* brother [much less someone else's brother].'
- *ne ludit quidem cum fratre suo*, 'He doesn't even play with his own brother [much less speak with him].'